# Data query from within Excel failing for some users when reading SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, encryption

A bit of background.

An end user wrote a data query from Excel to a new master data table my group developed and deployed.  In May, we encountered an error when she attempted to execute it.  We created an internal ticket with our IT group, and the problem was resolved within a day or so.

In the intervening months, the DBA who solved the problem left the company, and we want to expand the use of said Excel spreadsheet with Data Query to a larger audience.  When expanding to a larger audience, each user receives the same response the initial user did back in May.  The DBA is gone, and there are no notes on the ticket describing the resolution.

The actual User Experience is as such.:

1. User goes into Excel workbook, and wishes to refresh data.
2. User is prompted with a window asking for credentials.  Radio button determines whether to use "Current Credentials" or use "Username/Password" pair.   User credentials are selected.
3. Excel messages via a new pop-up with the following text: "Encryption Support       We are unable to connect to the data source using an encrypted connection. To access this data source using an unencrypted connection, click OK"
4. Clicking OK does not work, and we receive message that a connection was not made.

All queries embedded in the spreadsheet have "encryption" disabled at the query specification in the Data Source Settings.

I have looked at SQL Server permissions and Data Source settings from Excel.

The initial user can successfully refresh the Excel spreadsheet data.  The spreadsheet is in a shared folder on the local network.  Any other users attempting to refresh the data receive the response described in the question.

Comment: Could be related to this post in May, [Excel Encryption Error](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-encryption-error/m-p/3809482). The respondent mentions TLS (well, they say "TSL") which begs the question... what version and patch level of SQL Server are you attempting to connect to? (i.e.: what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`?) The older 1.0 and 1.1 versions of TLS are deprecated due to security issues and TLS 1.2 is the (currently) recommended minimum. SQL Server 2016 and later support TLS 1.2 out of the box but earlier versions need service pack updates to enable TLS 1.2.

Comment: Agreed this is likely a TLS issue. Please give: exact version and build number of SQL Server, and of Windows installed on both the server and client machines. Also is SQL Server set to Force Encryption?